# What is the best way add values to results form a query in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have an express api with an endpoint that performs a findById query on model `Community`. Then I need to inject a key value pair to that result based on a query that I make to another model. So for that reason I did the following

```
community.is_member = value
```

But it turned out that this doesn't result in what I wanted. In the JSON response that the endpoint sends there is no `is_member: value`. So figured I need to do the following.

```
community._doc.is_member = value
```

This actually works and the response is as I want it to be. But I don't know why I need to do so. I also want to figure out if there is a better way to do it.

So I guess my questions are why I need add the key value pair to the `_doc` object and is there a better way to add values to the result received after performing a query? For better understanding, I have included full code of the controller method bellow .

```
exports.show = catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
  // Gets a particular community based on the community id passed in the parameter
  const community = await Community.findById(req.params.id).populate("leader");

  // Checks if the requesting user is a member of the community or not
  community._doc.is_member = !!(await UserCommunity.findOne({
    user_id: req.user._id,
    community_id: community._id,
  }));

  // Sends response
  res.status(200).json({
    status: "success",
    community,
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, Mongoose queries return an instance of the Mongoose Document class. Documents are much heavier than vanilla JavaScript objects, because they have a lot of internal state for change tracking. Enabling the lean option tells Mongoose to skip instantiating a full Mongoose document and just give you the POJO.

```
const res = await MyModel.findOne().lean();
res.key = value;
```

[src](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you're trying to take a model returned from a Mongoose query, enrich it with a new property, and return it to the browser. This is not the correct order - *models* are not meant to be used as bags of properties that you can modify as you wish.

Instead, you should produce a so-called Plain Old JS Object (POJSO) based on the data contained in the model, add your property there and return the enriched object. This allows you to separate the behavior of the application (the model) and the presentation of data (the view).

Implement a method with a name that indicates its purpose - something like `toObject`, `toPOJSO`, `toDTO` (this tells users that the object is a Data Transfer Object - meant to be sent over the network). Alternatively, if you'd like the JSON representation of the object to always look in a given way, you can implement a `toJSON` method so that it serves a dual function (though it's better to have them separate, and have one call the other - this lets you split them more easily in the future if needed).

Comment: I don not quiet understand what you are saying. Isn't the result of awaiting a mongoose query already a JavaScript object. Why do I need to convert it separately. I have updated my question and added the full block of code for more clarity.

Comment: @sammanadhikari Yes, it's an object with particular methods, but it does not expose its data directly. By convention, in JavaScript, properties starting with underscore (`_`) are *private* - programmers are not supposed to refer to them from the outside of the object (only by `this._property`). This allows you to build *abstractions* that encapsulate access to data, and is the foundation of OOP.